# MS Access error: relationships must be on same number of fields with the same data types

Tags: ms-access, relational-database, field, relationship, primary-key

I have been assigned to create a database. The information given was to create the database partially from MS Excel, so I figured out how to import the data and create different tables that pertain to my task.

I am, however, unable to create any relationships between MS Access tables. I have double checked that the data types are the same between corresponding tables.

For example:

Table *Vendor*:

- VendorID *(autonumber)*
- VendorName *(short text)*

...that I am trying to connect to a Vendor field (short text) within a Product detail table.

I think one of the issues may be that there is duplicate information in the tables because the same vendors pop up multiple times.

I have already created a search query and form but it does not work: I suspect this is due to a lack of relationships between tables.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have your **VendorID** set as the *same datatype* in both the tables.

**N.B:** Even if it is stored as a number, make sure they are both long integers. The duplicates shouldn't prevent you from creating a relationship: 
**duplicates restrict only** when you try and create a **relationship with referential integrity.**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In one table I had guestID as a primary key with the AutoNumber format, and had a 1 to many relationship with guestID in a different table. I must have put the format to Short Text by accident, so when I changed it to Number, it got rid of the problem.